# Macports Installed Python 2.7 Inccorectly Imports Python 3.5 Numpy

Tags: python, numpy, macports

I have a macports installed python however, whenever I try to import numpy after launching python I get the following error message:

> > Python 2.7.11 (default, Mar  1 2016, 18:40:10) 
> >     [GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.0.2 (clang-700.1.81)] on darwin
> >     Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
> >
> > > import numpy
> > >       Traceback (most recent call last):
> > >         File "", line 1, in 
> > >         File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/**init**.py", line 180, in 
> > >           from . import add_newdocs
> > >         File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/add_newdocs.py", line 13, in 
> > >           from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
> > >         File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/lib/**init**.py", line 8, in 
> > >           from .type_check import *
> > >         File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/lib/type_check.py", line 11, in 
> > >           import numpy.core.numeric as _nx
> > >         File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/core/**init**.py", line 14, in 
> > >           from . import multiarray
> > >       ImportError: cannot import name multiarray

I should also add that I have py27-numpy installed.. however python27 always seems to look for py35-numpy.

Comment: Might be the syntax and usage differences between 2.7 and 3.5

Comment: Do you have PYTHONPATH set in your environment?

Comment: yup that's it! my PYTHONPATH is pointing to the wrong place